# allocating space to list<int> pointers using malloc not working

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class graph
{

    int v;
    list<int> *adj;
    void dfsutil(int v,bool visited []);
    public:
    graph(int v)
    {
        this->v=v;
        //adj = new list<int>[v];
        adj = (list<int> *)malloc(v*sizeof(list<int>));
    }
    void addedge(int v,int w);
    void dfs(int v);
};


void graph::addedge(int v,int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}

void graph::dfsutil(int v,bool visited[])
{
    list<int>::iterator i;
    cout<<v<<" ";
    visited[v]=true;

    for(i=adj[v].begin();i!=adj[v].end();i++)
    {
        if(!visited[*i])
            dfsutil(*i,visited);
    }
}

void graph::dfs(int v)
{
    int i=0;
    bool visited[this->v];
    for(i=0;i<this->v;i++)
        visited[i]=false;
    dfsutil(v,visited);
    for(i=0;i<v;i++)//this loop is required if there are multiple component of the graph
        if(!visited[i])
            dfsutil(i,visited);
}

int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    graph g(4);
    g.addedge(0, 1);
    g.addedge(0, 2);
    g.addedge(1, 2);
    g.addedge(2, 0);
    g.addedge(2, 3);
    g.addedge(3, 3);

    cout << "Following is Depth First Traversal (starting from vertex 2) \n";
    g.dfs(2);

    return 0;
}
```

in the above code if try to allocate space for list *adj using malloc as written above,it does not work fine whereas if we use new,it works fine as its written in commented part above,i cant figure out why

Comment: Stop using `malloc` in a C++ program.  It doesn't work because using `malloc` for non-POD types is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You're already using a `std::list` so you don't have to use an `int *`. Use a container of lists so you don't have to use a `list<int> *`. From what you've shown, you leak the memory you allocate.

Comment: Also, use a `std::vector<std::list<int>>`.  You made an effort to use a container to store your int's, so use one to store your lists.

Comment: The reason malloc isn't working is that it doesn't do anything but allocation. The object will have to be correctly initialized. That is what the new does apart from allocation. And you should do what PaulMcKenzie said don't use either malloc or new, use the correct container objects.

Comment: Thumb rule: Don't use malloc/free  for C++ functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not create an array of `std::list` **objects** when you used `malloc`.  All `malloc` does is allocate memory from the heap -- no objects are created.  Thus attempting to use your `std::list`'s as if they are created correctly will result in *undefined behavior*.

You should use a container such as `std::vector` to store your list objects:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

class graph
{
    int v;
    std::vector<std::list<int>> adj;
    void dfsutil(int v,bool visited []);
    public:
        graph(int num) : v(num), adj(num) {}
    void addedge(int v,int w);
    void dfs(int v);
};
```

Note there is no need to allocate memory.  The rest of your code should stay the same, since `vector` has an overloaded `operator []` to access the items.